# Tailoring RegionPlot3D with PlotPoints?

Tags: plotting

This seemingly tame solid gives *Mathematica* (v9) a bit of a workout if you want to generate a good picture:

```
rinner[y_] = Sqrt[y];
router[y_] = 1;
RegionPlot3D[rinner[y]^2 <= x^2 + z^2 <= router[y]^2, 
  {x, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[.75], MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I kept increasing `PlotPoints` from 100 to 200 to 300 and things get pretty slow---without much of an improvement in the rendering of the choppy part of the region at the top. Bumping up `MaxRecursion` and `PerformanceGoal->"Quality"` didn't seem to help.

I tried playing with variations like `PlotPoints->{100,100,300}` to get better results faster, and this leads to my two questions.

1. What else should I try? (I experimented with `RevolutionPlot3D`, but I want *solids*.)
2. Is it possible to tailor the placement of `PlotPoints` to a subset of either

   (a) an axis (say, 10x more points in the $z$ direction, but pack them into $0.9\le z\le 1$?, or

   (b) a specific portion of the overall space (say, $x,y,z$ with $0.9^2\le x^2+y^2\le 1^2$ and $0.9\le z\le 1$, etc.)?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to stick with `RegionPlot3D` but don't want the jagged edges, then you can smooth them by excluding the creased line from the plot region:

```
rinner[y_] = Sqrt[y];
router[y_] = 1;
ε = .05;
RegionPlot3D[(rinner[y])^2 <= x^2 + z^2 <= (router[y])^2 && 
  router[y] - rinner[y] > ε, {x, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 
  1}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[.75], MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 5]
```

[image: rounded]

Edges are always rounded in `RegionPlot3D` anyway, so rounding them by hand as I did here with the parameter `ε` may be acceptable.

The small parameter `ε` determines how close the inner and outer walls are allowed to come - thus preventing them from touching. The choice of `PlotPoints` will determine how small you can make `ε`.

Comment: Very nice--and quick---result. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

The big problem you have here is, that `RegionPlot3D` really tries to determine the inner of your object. On the top you have an extremely thin rim and `RegionPlot3D` would have to find the same rim high on a circular boundary. Too hard, at least for the standard settings.

You could try to plot only the contour of your object:

```
ContourPlot3D[ {router[y]^2 == x^2 + z^2 , rinner[y]^2 == x^2 + z^2},
   {x, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 PlotPoints -> 20, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.75],
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Well, now this is embarrassing...

Comment: @halirutan: Should AxesLabel->{x,y,z} be changed to AxesLabel->{x,z,y} in this image?