# High-quality RegionPlot3D for logical combinations of predicates

Tags: plotting, regions

Unlike `RegionPlot`, `RegionPlot3D` copes poorly with logical combinations of predicates (`&&`, `||`), which should result in sharp edges in the region to be plotted. Instead, these edges are usually drawn rounded and sometimes with severe aliasing artifacts. This has been observed in many posts on this site:

- [Problem in RegionPlot3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10548/484)
- [on RegionPlot3D and ContourPlot3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24927/484)
- [Tailoring RegionPlot3D with PlotPoints?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16395/484)
- "[`RegionPlot3D` plots always seem to have that 'home-made' look about them...](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25059/484)"
- "[...the limitations of `RegionPlot3D` make the edges appear jagged.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48482/484)"

One solution, as noted [by Silvia](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24933/484), [by halirutan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16396/484), and most recently [by Jens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48482/484), is to use a `ContourPlot3D` instead with an appropriate `RegionFunction`, as this produces much higher-quality results. I think it would be useful to have a general-purpose solution along these lines. That is, we want a single function that can be used as a drop-in replacement for `RegionPlot3D` and will automatically produce high-quality results by setting up the appropriate instances of `ContourPlot3D`.

Here is a test example, inspired by [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41985/484):

```
RegionPlot3D[1/4 <= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1 && (x <= 0 || y >= 0),
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

It should look more like this (created by increasing `PlotPoints`, and even then the edges are not perfectly sharp):

[image]

Comment: Finally, thanks for the thread. :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is based on Rahul's ideas, but a different implementation:

```
contourRegionPlot3D[region_, {x_, x0_, x1_}, {y_, y0_, y1_}, {z_, z0_, z1_}, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{reg, preds},
  reg = LogicalExpand[region && x0 <= x <= x1 && y0 <= y <= y1 && z0 <= z <= z1];
  preds = Union@Cases[reg, _Greater | _GreaterEqual | _Less | _LessEqual, -1];
  Show @ Table[ContourPlot3D[
     Evaluate[Equal @@ p], {x, x0, x1}, {y, y0, y1}, {z, z0, z1}, 
     RegionFunction -> Function @@ {{x, y, z}, Refine[reg, p] && Refine[! reg, ! p]},
     RegionBoundaryStyle -> None, opts], {p, preds}]]
```

(**update** - added `RegionBoundaryStyle -> None` which is required in v12.2)

Examples:

```
contourRegionPlot3D[
 (x < 0 || y > 0) && 0.5 <= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 0.99,
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

```
contourRegionPlot3D[
 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 2 && x^2 + y^2 <= (z - 1)^2 && Abs@x >= 1/4,
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

```
contourRegionPlot3D[
 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 0.4 || 0.01 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 0.05,
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

## How it works

Firstly `LogicalExpand` is used to split up multiple inequalities into a combination of single inequalities, for example to convert `0 < x < 1` into `0 < x && x < 1`.

Like Rahul's code, an inequality like `x < 1` is converted to the equality `x == 1` to define a part of the surface enclosing the region. We do not generally want the entire `x == 1` plane though, only that part for which the true/false value of the region function is determined solely by the true/false value of `x < 1`.

This is done by plotting the surface with a `RegionFunction` like this:

```
Refine[reg, p] && Refine[! reg, ! p]
```

which is equivalant to the predicate "reg is true when p is true, and reg is false when p is false"

Comment: Fantastic! Can you write a little about how it works? The `Refine` trick is very interesting and a little mysterious.

Comment: @RahulNarain, thanks. I added a few words about how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That's very ingenious! By the way, I would find the line easier to understand if written as `Refine[reg, p] && Refine[! reg, ! p]`, unless there's some subtle difference I'm not seeing.

Comment: @RahulNarain, I think they should be equivalent, and I agree it's clearer that way.

Comment: This is wonderful. I notice though that when I copy/paste your code and examples, my region is all shaded orange rather than the colors shown here. I'm using Mathematica version 11.1.1.0. Is there a way I can easily tweak the code to assign a color individually to each bounding surface?

Comment: @j0equ1nn, the orange coloring is the new default style for 3D graphics (since version 10 I think). You can get the old coloring with the option `PlotTheme -> "Classic"`. To get different colors for each bounding surface you could use something like `ContourStyle :> RandomColor[]`

Comment: With this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182004/discordance-in-plots) your exellente code dosen't work? 
Maybe there is a way to make it happen.

Comment: I'm running Mathematica 12.0.0.0 and copy/pasting this code is not working. I'm getting `Show: No graphical objects to show.`. Might I be running it wrong? Or did something change in version 12 that broke this?

Comment: Thank you so much. Amazing answer.

Answer (score 17):

This is not a complete answer. It only handles cases where each predicate is a single inequality, and they are combined only by `And`. So, for example, `0 <= x <= 1` will have to be rewritten as `0 <= x && x <= 1`, while for `x <= 0 || y >= 0` I don't have a solution yet. A complete general solution is still desired.

Suppose the combined predicate is $p = p_1 \wedge p_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge p_n$. Now $p$ can change from true to false if and only if one of the $p_i$ does while all the other $p_j$ are true. So the boundary of the region defined by $p$ consists of several pieces, namely the boundaries of each $p_i$ restricted to the region $\bigwedge_{j\ne i}p_j$. If $p_i$ is, say, $f\le g$, then said boundary is the contour $f=g$ in the specified region.

And so:

```
Options[myRegionPlot3D] = Options[ContourPlot3D];
myPatchPlot3D[eq_, preds_, {x_, x0_, x1_}, {y_, y0_, y1_}, {z_, z0_, z1_}, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 ContourPlot3D[eq, {x, x0, x1}, {y, y0, y1}, {z, z0, z1}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, And @@ preds], opts]
myRegionPlot3D[pred_, {x_, x0_, x1_}, {y_, y0_, y1_}, {z_, z0_, z1_}, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 With[{preds = List @@ (pred && x0 <= x && x <= x1 && y0 <= y && y <= y1 && z0 <= z && z <= z1)}, 
  Show @@ Table[
    myPatchPlot3D[Equal @@ preds[[i]], Delete[preds, i], 
     {x, x0, x1}, {y, y0, y1}, {z, z0, z1}, opts], {i, Length@preds}]]
```

It can't do the example in the question, but it can do this:

```
myRegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 2 && x^2 + y^2 <= (z - 1)^2 && Abs@x >= 1/4,
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

which the default `RegionPlot3D` is bad at:

[image]

Another limitation is that the mesh lines don't line up.

Comment: Nice idea. Not really thought this through, but if you use `f = BooleanConvert[LogicalExpand[#], "ESOP"] &` to convert the predicate to an exclusive sum of products, I think you should split the region into distinct parts which you can use your code on. e.g. `Show @@ (myRegionPlot3D[#, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}] & /@ f[1/4 <= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1 && (x <= 0 || y >= 0)])`

Comment: @Simon: That's neat! I wasn't aware of `BooleanConvert`.