# Graphics3D from Mathematica to SolidWorks (for 3D-printing)

Tags: export, graphics3d, 3d-printing

I have an 3D Graphic generated with Mathematica's Graphics3D, and want to use it later in SolidWorks. SolidWorks files are usually *.stp, *.step, *.stl extentions.

google search hasn't given me a solution yet, and I didn't find anything on this page either.

Are there solutions to that? What is the best way to do this? Or do you know any workarounds?

**edit:**
Just for info - my 3D Graphics (from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48503/plotting-a-spericon-and-bipyramid-with-100-faces)) is:

```
Graphics3D[{GraphicsComplex[
   Join[{Cos[#], Sin[#], 0} & /@ Range[0, Pi, Pi/(25)], {{0, 0, 1}}], 
   {
    {#, Rotate[Rotate[#, 180 °, {0, 0, 1}], 90 °, {0, 1, 0}]} &[
         GeometricTransformation[Polygon[{##, 27} & @@@ Partition[Range[26], 2, 1]],  
                                 {IdentityMatrix[3], ScalingTransform[{1, 1, -1}]}]
     ]
    }]}]
```

**edit2:**
Thanks to Simon Woods' wonderful answere, I was able to export to Solid Works, and print it with my 3D-printer. Here are real-world results:

[image: 100-sided Sphericon 1]
[image: 100-sided Sphericon 2]

Thanks alot again :)

Comment: `Export[path.stl,something in 3D]` works for me. Then I don't know if SolidWorks can handle it.

Comment: Thanks Öska, looks promising. Unfortunatly, I got a error when writing this, namely: `Export::nodta: "Graphics3D contains no data that can be exported to the \!\(\"STL\"\) format. "`. I added my instruction above, could you try whether it works for you?

Comment: I found a video with Solidworks with Mathematica. I thought it was cool to share: https://youtu.be/grGauPYuYSs

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use `Normal` to explicitly apply the various transformations, resulting in an ordinary collection of polygons which `Export` can translate to STL. Unfortunately, it looks like `Normal` has a problem when multiple transformations are supplied to `GeometricTransformation`. We need to handle this with a specific rule.

Assuming `g` is your `Graphics3D`:

```
gn = Normal[g /. GeometricTransformation[prims_, tf_List] :>
    (GeometricTransformation[prims, #] & /@ tf)]

Export["test.stl", gn]
```

This produces an output file. I do not have SolidWorks to tell if it's any good or not.

Comment: works great for me, I can open the file without problems in SolidWorks. Thank you!

Comment: Works great. I am able to check the success immediately because it is standard to my system viewer on MacOS Catalina.

Answer (score 1):

The Mathematica Package below exports to either of two popular raytracer file formats (not 3ds which is proprietary/binary), and can be used Live in Mathematica interactively/Live.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/rayshade-math/

I'm interested myself if anyone is exporting to a Cuda rendering suite or even 3DStudio ARt Renderer and how well Export[] did (in the past export was very poor, i have no copy of 3dstudio to check today's results - but do not have fingers crossed since Wolfram only shows pics being exported not their results?)

Comment: Mathematica has import/export to institutional formats for geo mapping and chemical.  For most, those are the work-horses and more the focus - but i have no idea there how well mm does exporting.  Importing wise, Mathematica can use maps we all know that!

Comment: Please, make it more self contained -- did you write the software, license, code samples, what if the link goes down or it is pulled out of the VC, etc, etc.