# Controlling quality of discretized region meshes

Tags: finite-element-method, regions, version-10

**EDIT**:

Impact of this problem has been considerably lessened in v10.2. Although new version is still not performing analytical discretization at sharp corners (there are jaggies), evenness of sampling seems better and the `MaxCellMeasure` option is actually obeyed in the expected manner. This makes discretization much more usable.

For an example:

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionDifference[Ball[], Ball[{0, 0, 1}]], 
 MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> 0.0025}]
```

> [image]

---

I want to discretize 3D constructive solids, supported by Mathematica 10 regions functionality. Quality of resulting meshes must be controllable, and meshes must be useful for further computation.

This should be easy, but the trivial example below stuns me.

```
(* Simple derived region in 3D with a sharp edge: *)
r = RegionDifference[Ball[{0, 0, 0}], Ball[{0, 0, 1}]];

(* RegionPlot3D with PlotPoints handles this reasonably well: *)
RegionPlot3D[r, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

> [image]

```
(* This should create a discretized mesh, and it does, but with poor quality: *)
DiscretizeRegion[r]
```

> [image]

Edges are noticeably jaggy. This is understandable, and usually option like `PlotPoints` fixes these kind of issues. `DiscretizeRegion` has numerous options which should affect quality of its' output. I think I've played with all of them.

Biggest difference I've seen has been is through use of `MaxCellMeasure`, but interestingly enough, same ugly jaggies stay there even if complexity of the mesh itself increases. I would need an option like `PlotPoints` which apparently affects grid resolution of a marching cubes style algorithm in `RegionPlot3D`, but there isn't one for `DiscretizeRegion`. Any suggestions?

Comment: For those looking at this question for visualization purposes I suggest taking a look at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48530/3056 - which, combining with `RegionMember` can produce very aesthetic surface renditions with nicely detailed sharp edges.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In principal you should be able to do

```
r = RegionDifference[Ball[{0, 0, 0}], Ball[{0, 0, 1}]];
rp = RegionPlot3D[r, PlotPoints -> 50];
DiscretizeGraphics[rp]
```

Unfortunately, this does not work and is hopefully improved in a future version.

One thing you can do, however, is use the finite element mesh generator for this:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
m = ToElementMesh[r, 
  "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {"RegionPlot", "SamplePoints" -> 50}, 
  "MeshOrder" -> 1]
```

You can then convert the ElementMesh to a MeshRegion simply by using

```
MeshRegion[m]
```

Note that in this case `MeshRegion` does not show it's output since it's beyond a threshold (too big). It has some 300000 tetrahedron elements.

You can force it to display with

```
Show[MeshRegion[m]]
```

[image]

The `"MeshOrder"` is set to one (= linear elements) and the `"SamplePoints"` correspond to the `PlotPoints` in `RegionPlot`. There is more information about boundary mesh generation in [ToBoundaryMesh](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToBoundaryMesh.html), [ToElementMesh](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToElementMesh.html), [ElementMesh](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ElementMesh.html) and the related [mesh generation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html#509267359) and [element mesh visualization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshVisualization.html#509267359) tutorial.

One last thing I should add, is that the 3D stuff does have some rough edges.

**Update version 12.1:**

In version 12.1 you can use the [OpenCascadeLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/UsingOpenCascadeLink.html) to do the following:

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
r = RegionDifference[Ball[{0, 0, 0}], Ball[{0, 0, 1}]];
ocr = OpenCascadeShapeBooleanRegion[r]
(* OpenCascadeShapeExpression[3] *)

bmeshOC = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[ocr];
bmeshOC["Wireframe"[
  "MeshElementStyle" -> Directive[FaceForm[Green], EdgeForm[Red]]]]
```

[image]

And even simpler, you can use:

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[r, "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> "OpenCascade"]
mesh["Wireframe"[
  "MeshElementStyle" -> Directive[FaceForm[Green], EdgeForm[Red]]]]
```

Comment: Whoa, thanks! I'm a bit surprised `FEM` exposes this, instead of `DiscretizeRegion`, where I'd expect it to live now. Hoping to see those rough edges (pun intended) smoothed out in the future!

Comment: @kirma, `DiscretizeRegion` should give proper results via `AccuraryGoal` and `PrecidionGoal` but that's not implemented fully for 3D. The FEM stuff exposes this to allow maximum 'hackability' and in this case that allows for a workaround. If you do find stuff that does not work, please, by all means send it to support such that it can be looked at and get fixed. Thanks.

Comment: good to see you back alive, user21 :-). Is it possible to refine the grid only near the edge, in one way or another?

Comment: @AlbertRetey, well yes back to get the geometry and FEM stuff started ;-). You could use `"MaxBoundaryCellMeasure"` to refine the boundary; this works well in 2D. However, in 3D this does not yet influence the sampling of the boundary. Also, since this region has some thin parts to it it would generate quite a lot more elements.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to do what you want using `DiscretizeGraphics` as suggested by @user21. No need to call `NDSolve`FEM`

```
r = RegionDifference[Ball[{0, 0, 0}], Ball[{0, 0, 1}]]

rp = RegionPlot3D[r, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we discretize the `Graphics` object with the following clever replacements that somehow works:

```
DiscretizeGraphics[Normal[rp /. {(PlotRange -> _) :> 
     PlotRange -> All, (Lighting -> _) :> Lighting -> Automatic}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get even finer mesh, increase `PlotPoints` in `RegionPlot` (this will increase the time it takes to render the `RegionPlot`), then proceed as before. I used `PlotPoints -> 100` for the image below:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @user21, I can't seem to get the mesh as fine as that produced from `NDSolve`FEM in your answer. I've tried various options: `MeshQualityGoal`, `MaxCellMeasure` etc. They don't seem to have any effect. Unless I increase `PlotPoints` in `RegionPlot` which takes a while to render. Any suggestions?

Comment: but using `NDSolve`FEM` is the best part of it.... ;-) I think that `MaxCellMeasure` is not working is a bug. `MeshQualityGoal` has no much to do with the number of tets generated. It tries to generate tets that have certain quality [see here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html)

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not so much about controlling the quality, but pointing out that Mma v13 introduces constructive solid geometry for some basic primitives such as `Ball`s, and is capable of producing much more sensible discretizations for those out of the box:

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[CSGRegion["Difference", {Ball[{0, 0, 0}],
                                                  Ball[{0, 0, 1}]}]]
```

[image]