# Boundary discretize region of ellipsoid returns a three dimensional region

Tags: numerical-integration, regions, mesh

I need to integrate a rather complicated function on an ellipsoidal surface, specifically a prolate spheroid surface.

Im using the mathematica 10 feature of discretize the regions in mesh and pass the discretized region to NIntegrate.

However when i define the ellipsoidal surface region as:

```
region = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
 Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0.125, 0.125}], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1]
```

and i do

```
RegionDimension[region]
```

the answer is 3 so it is discretizing the whole volume not only the surface.

To confirm what seen above i computed the Integral in the case of a sphere:

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01]]
```

whose result is 4.1798 that is $\approx \frac{4}{3} \pi$ confirming that he is performing the integration over the VOLUME not over the surface...

Am i doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: What you probably want is `DiscretizeRegion` on the `RegionBoundary` of your ellipsoid. If you look at `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` documentation you can see the result doesn't consist of the boundary alone... it's just that discretization occurs only on it.

Comment: I did it, hower when i do     DiscretizeRegion[
 RegionBoundary[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0.125, 0.125}]], 
 MeshQualityGoal -> 10]      the result is the same whatever MeshQualitiGoal  or MaxCellMeasure i specify. i don't know why

Comment: Related: [/86196](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86196/how-do-i-create-a-triangulated-surface-from-points/)

Comment: I solved the problem in the following way:   region = RegionBoundary[
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0.125, 0.125}], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1]]   in this way i can specify the mesh quality without any problem

Comment: @user3810266 BTW: `MaxCellMeasure` is not really reliable on pre-v10.2 versions; see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54925/controlling-quality-of-discretized-region-meshes . Also, you don't really need to perform discretization in many cases at all!

Comment: What do you mean that i don't need to discretize at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After thinking about it, i solved the problem by considering:

```
region = RegionBoundary[
 BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0.125, 0.125}], 
 MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1]]
```

in this only the surface is discretized and the mesh quality can be specified by MaxCellMeasure.