# How to plot the ranges of the variables of an iterated integral?

Tags: plotting, regions

I would like to plot the volume of the following integral:

$$\int _{-1}^1\int _0^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\int _{x^2+y^2}^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\left(xyz\right)dzdxdy$$

Here are the ranges of the variables from this iterated integral.

$$-1\le y\le 1 $$

$$0 \le x\le \sqrt{1-y^2}$$

$$x^2+y^2\le z\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

This is the right half of a region which lower bound is an elliptic paraboloid and the upper bound is a cone.

I have no previous experience with Mathematica so I have only managed to plot a elliptic paraboloid and a cone:

> ContourPlot3D[{z == x ^2 + y^2, z^2 == x ^2 + y^2}, {x, -2,    2}, {y,
>   -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]

I have tried this alternatives but the results are "empty":

> RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 <= (x^2 + y^2)^1/2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
>
> Plot3D[{ (x^2 + y^2), (x^2 - y^2)^1/2}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
>    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, (x^2 + y^2) < (x^2 - y^2)^1/2]]
>
> RegionPlot3D[
>    z <= Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] && y^2 + x^2 < 0 && z > 0, {x, -1.5, 
>     1.5}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 100]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the region, you can use region plot, you should take the limits of the integral exactly as they are written and supply them to the function, separating the region corresponding to each integral by the `And` function(&&). The edge is a little jagged, but you can play with the number of plot points to get a better or worse picture.

```
RegionPlot3D[
 -1 <= y <= 1 && 0 < x < Sqrt[1 - y^2] && 
  x^2 + y^2 < z < Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]
 , {y, -1, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}
 , PlotPoints -> 100
 , PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"
 , PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.5]], Mesh -> None
 , BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 1}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Weirdly enough, I obtained a  more regular, "prettier" picture using your code as posted ([link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ang3U.png)). Is it possible that the one you posted was obtained using far fewer than 100 points? (+1)

Comment: Must have. :/ Fixed.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48486)?

Comment: Wow! That's a huge improvement. I'll have to read it closely when I've got the time.

Answer (score 4):

Using `ImplicitRegion`

```
rgn = ImplicitRegion[-1 <= y <= 1 && 0 <= x <= Sqrt[1 - y^2] && 
    x^2 + y^2 <= z <= Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, y, z}];

RegionPlot3D[rgn,
 PlotPoints -> 150,
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel ->
  (Style[#, Bold, 14] & /@ {"x", "y", "z"})]
```

[image]

The volume is

```
vol = Volume[rgn]
```

> Pi/12

or alternatively,

```
vol == RegionMeasure[rgn, 3] ==
 Integrate[1, Element[{x, y, z}, rgn]] ==
 Integrate[1, {y, -1, 1}, {x, 0, Sqrt[1 - y^2]},
  {z, x^2 + y^2, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}]
```

> True

Your original integral is

```
Integrate[x*y*z, Element[{x, y, z}, rgn]]
```

> 0