# Region bounded by x^2+y^2=1, y=z, x=0, z=0, in first octant

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, regions

I need to draw (pencil and paper) the region bounded by $x^2+y^2=1$, $y=z$, $x=0$, and $z=0$ in the first octant. So the first assistance I asked of Mathematica is:

```
ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, y == z, x == 0, z == 0}, {x, 0, 1}, {y,
   0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
 ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5],
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 ViewPoint -> {3, -0.5, 1.5}]
```

Which gave me this image:

[image]

I was then able to draw the image via pencil and paper. Then I thought I'd try RegionFunction.

```
ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, y == z, x == 0, z == 0}, {x, 0, 1}, {y,
   0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, y <= Sqrt[1 - x^2] && z <= y],
 ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5],
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 ViewPoint -> {3, -0.5, 1.5}]
```

Which gave me this image.

[image]

I was able to repair it by extending my inequalities a bit.

```
ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, y == z, x == 0, z == 0}, {x, 0, 1}, {y,
   0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, y <= Sqrt[1 - x^2] + 0.001 && z <= y + 0.001],
 ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5],
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 ViewPoint -> {3, -0.5, 1.5}]
```

Which gave me this image.

[image]

Now, I am aware of RegionPlot3D, but I am not fond of the images it produces, although it is an easy method to get a quick idea of what the image looks like. So, I started trying a little ParametricPlot3D.

```
Show[
 Plot3D[y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, Sqrt[1 - x^2]},
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}],
 ParametricPlot3D[{x, Sqrt[1 - x^2], z}, {x, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 
   Sqrt[1 - x^2]},
  PlotStyle -> {LightBlue, Opacity[0.8]}],
 ViewPoint -> {3, -0.5, 1.5}
 ]
```

Which gave me a little bit of strangeness. See the little sudden dipping in the border of the blue side as it approaches the x-axis?

[image]

I tried my contour inequality (adding 0.001 here an there) extension approach in several ways, but I could not get it to disappear. Any thoughts?

**Update:** There is some extremely wonderful work on this page, but I'd also like to add a cylindrical plot based on MichaelE2's suggestion.

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{u Cos[t], u Sin[t], u Sin[t]}, {t, 0, Pi}, {u, 
   0, 1},
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], u Sin[t]}, {t, 0, Pi/2}, {u, 0, 1},
   PlotStyle -> {LightBlue, Opacity[0.8]}], 
 ViewPoint -> {3, -0.5, 1.5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48486)?

Comment: Note one can do better in cylindrical coordinates and especially with direct construction of the surfaces.  But judging from previous posts, I think the OP would prefer solutions that preserve the equations of the surfaces in cartesian coordinates -- Is that right, David?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, cylindrical would be OK.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A simple alternative is to use [`Plot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D.html) with both [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) and [`Filling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html).

```
Plot3D[y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
 RegionFunction ->
  Function[{x, y, z},
   x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0],
 Filling -> 0,
 FillingStyle -> Opacity[.75],
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5],
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y, z}),
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 ViewPoint -> {3, -1.5, 0.75}]
```

[image]

EDIT: I recommend that you experiment with different settings for [`PlotTheme`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotTheme.html) to determine which is best for your classroom and smartboard.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, 
    x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0],
  Filling -> 0,
  FillingStyle -> Opacity[.75],
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 18, Bold] & /@
     {x, y, z}),
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
  ViewPoint -> {3, -1.5, 0.75},
  PlotTheme -> pt],
 {{pt, "Classic", "Plot Theme"},
  {"Business", "Classic", "Default",
   "Detailed", "Marketing", "Minimal",
   "Monochrome", "Scientific", "Web"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, the easiest for the students to understand. I have another question. We use Smartboards in our classrooms to display our Mathematica images. What type of coloring in this example would make this image the easiest to see and interpret for students sitting in the back of the room and viewing the presentation on the Smartboard?

Comment: Really nice going. I am going to give this a test today.

Answer (score 8):

As pointed out by [J. M.♦](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m), [Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods)'s  approach in [#48486](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48486/high-quality-regionplot3d-for-logical-combinations-of-predicates) could be used.

```
sharpregplot[
  region_,
  {x_, x0_, x1_},
  {y_, y0_, y1_},
  {z_, z0_, z1_},
  opts : OptionsPattern[]
] := Module[
  {reg, preds},
  reg = LogicalExpand[region && x0 <= x <= x1 && y0 <= y <= y1 && z0 <= z <= z1];
  preds = Union@Cases[reg, _Greater | _GreaterEqual | _Less | _LessEqual, -1];
  Show @ Table[
    ContourPlot3D[
      Evaluate[Equal @@ p],
      {x, x0, x1},
      {y, y0, y1},
      {z, z0, z1},
      RegionFunction -> Function @@ {{x, y, z}, Refine[reg, p] && Refine[! reg, ! p]},
      opts
    ],
    {p, preds}
  ]
]
```

Then,

```
sharpregplot[
  y^2 <= 1 - x^2 && z <= y,
  {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
  BoundaryStyle -> None,
  ContourStyle -> RandomColor[],
  Mesh -> None,
  ViewPoint -> 1000 {3, -0.5, 1.5}
]
```

gives

[image: Sharp RegionPlot3D]

Answer (score 6):

Here's one approach that uses `MeshFunctions` to highlight the parts of the bounding surfaces that belong to the region.  So many different approaches are possible....

```
opts = Options[ParametricPlot3D];
SetOptions[ParametricPlot3D,
  {Mesh -> {{0}, 15, 15},
   MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.],      (* ignored -- bug? *)
   MeshShading -> {{{Automatic, None}}}}];
mfn["y==z"] = Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, z - y];
mfn["x^2+y^2==1"] = Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, x^2 + y^2 - 1];
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {ColorData[97, 1], Opacity[0.8]},
  MeshFunctions -> {mfn["x^2+y^2==1"], #4 &, #5 &}],
 ParametricPlot3D[{x, Sqrt[1 - x^2], z}, {x, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {ColorData[97, 2], Opacity[0.8]},
  MeshFunctions -> {mfn["y==z"], #4 &, #5 &}],
 ParametricPlot3D[{0, y, z}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {ColorData[97, 3], Opacity[0.8]},
  MeshFunctions -> {mfn["y==z"], #4 &, #5 &}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, 0}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {ColorData[97, 4], Opacity[0.8]},
  MeshFunctions -> {mfn["x^2+y^2==1"], #4 &, #5 &}],
 ViewPoint -> {3, -0.5, 1.5}]
SetOptions[ParametricPlot3D, opts];
```

SE Uploader:

[image]

Hmm...it looks better on my screen (still a slight glitch in the corner):

[image]

Another bug?  This often means *Mathematica* is about to crash.  I think the OP has experienced this one before.  (Note: I don't think this is a problem with the uploader.  The same happens with `Export` and if I reevaluate the code.  It's a hard to reproduce problem in the FE. I'm on Mac OSX V10.2)

Answer (score 4):

Just to cover more ways of achieving this. We can plot over a `Disk` and use a `PlotTheme`.

```
Plot3D[y, {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {0, π/2}], PlotTheme -> "FilledSurface", 
  BoxRatios -> Automatic, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]