# Displaying on a Smartboard

Tags: plotting

I got a very nice answer on [Region bounded by x^2+y^2=1, y=z, x=0, z=0, in first octant](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98445/region-bounded-by-x2y2-1-y-z-x-0-z-0-in-first-octant), using this code:

```
Plot3D[y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
 RegionFunction ->
  Function[{x, y, z},
   x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0],
 Filling -> 0,
 FillingStyle -> Opacity[.75],
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5],
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y, z}),
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 ViewPoint -> {3, -1.5, 0.75}]
```

Which produces this image:

[image]

Bob Hanlon also provided a very nice Manipulate idea to explore the use of PlotThemes.

However, I'd still like to find out if there are folks on Mathematica Stack Exchange that use a [**Smartboard**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_Board) to present Mathematica images when teaching class, and if so, can you make the best recommendation for color effects (which I know little about) that produce an image on the Smartboard that is best visualized by the students in the room. I find the default colors to be too dark when viewing on the Smartboard. Do you have a favorite set of colors that work best when presenting an image on a Smartboard?

Comment: Hi, David, I have no experience with the smartboard, and cannot give an advice, but it seems reasonable to first play with the value of `Opacity `option. If you put it 0.7 or even 0.8 the image will be still transparent, but the colors will be better visible. Second, I would play with different `ColorSchemes`and see how do they perform on the smartboard, (see the continuation)

Comment: (Continuation) Like this, for example, like here: `Plot3D[y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0],
    Filling -> 0, FillingStyle -> Opacity[.75], PlotStyle -> Opacity[.8], 
   AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y, z}),  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ViewPoint -> {3, -1.5, 0.75}, ColorFunction -> #] & /@ ColorData["Gradients"] `. You might also use other color schemes. See the continuation

Comment: Continuation 2: Then, `Lighting` might also help, like here: `Plot3D[y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0],
    Filling -> 0, FillingStyle -> Opacity[.75], 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[.8], 
   AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y, z}), 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ViewPoint -> {3, -1.5, 0.75}, 
   ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Mesh -> None, 
   Lighting -> #] & /@ {Automatic, {{"Ambient", Red}}}`. But you need just to try. Have fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try experimenting with the colors. Below I change the values of given to `FillingStyle` and `PlotStyle`. This lightens things up quite a bit and, perhaps, more to your liking.

```
With[{style = {Opacity[.75], Glow[Yellow]}}, 
  Plot3D[y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
    RegionFunction -> 
      Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0],
    Filling -> 0,
    FillingStyle -> style,
    PlotStyle -> style,
    AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y, z}),
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
    ViewPoint -> {3, -1.5, 0.75}]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I am going to find this extremely useful. Thank you so much.