# Low resolution with RegionPlot3D

Tags: plotting, regions

To draw a cuboid with `RegionPlot3D` I can simply specify a function:

```
cuboidQ[{x_, y_, z_}, dim1_, dim2_, dim3_, center_: {0, 0, 0}] :=
  (Abs[x - center[[1]]] <= dim1 && 
   Abs[y - center[[2]]] <= dim2 && Abs[z - center[[3]]] <= dim3)
```

and the plot it with `RegionPlot3D`. Or, if I need to draw a cuboid that can be rotated by a certain angle around a specific axis I can simply change the function to this:

```
cuboidQ2[{x_, y_, z_}, dim1_, dim2_, dim3_, center_: {0, 0, 0}, ang_, 
  axis_, p_] := Module[{r, x1, y1, z1},
  r = RotationTransform[ang, axis, p];
  {x1, y1, z1} = r[{x, y, z}];
  (Abs[x1 - center[[1]]] <= dim1 && Abs[y1 - center[[2]]] <= dim2 && 
  Abs[z1 - center[[3]]] <= dim3)
]
```

and plot it:

```
RegionPlot3D[
  cuboidQ2[{x, y, z}, 25, 25, 25, {0, 0, 0}, 
  Pi/8, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}], {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}, {z, -50, 50},
  MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

However, the resolution is very bad. Of course, it can be improved by increasing the `PlotPoints` to about 250, but it seems unreasonable to have to turn the `PlotPoints` so high to get a decent resolution for such a simple shape.

Is there any better way to render this kind of shape with `RegionPlot3D`?

Comment: Have you quit your kernel? Your code works fine for me on 10.4.

Comment: I second Martin here: your code works fine on 10.4 (Win7-64).

Comment: @MartinBüttner Argh. Yes, it works.

Comment: Um, it may work technically, but it looks awful:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/7IxZY.png  I have to increase the `PlotPoints` to 100 and it only looks marginally better.

Comment: @MarcoB - Does it look better in version 10.4?  In 10.3 it's just awful, you can see the same problem with `DiscretizeRegion@
 ImplicitRegion[
  cuboidQ[{x Cos[π/8] - y Sin[π/8], 
    y Cos[π/8] + x Sin[π/8], z}, 25, 25, 25], {x, y, z}]`

Comment: @JasonB I have already 3D printed this kind of objects (the `cuboidQ` non-rotated version) and with `PlotPoints` set to 250 they looked great.

Comment: meh, I'm not impressed at all with the results of `RegionPlot3D` on such a simple region.  It is absolutely ridiculous to have to turn `PlotPoints` up so high to get a decent cube

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Update

The original method I proposed took advantage of the fact that the region created by applying `DiscretizeRegion` to a simple `Cuboid` object was represented perfectly by `RegionPlot3D`, even after applying any geometric transformation via `TransformedRegion`.  This results in a very fast `RegionPlot3D` that is superior to the (much slower) plot produced when you feed a series of predicates to `RegionPlot3D` directly.  However, the resulting 3D `MeshRegions` can not be fed to any of the constructive solid geometry (CSG) operations like `RegionDifference`, `RegionUnion`, and `RegionIntersection` (maybe in version 11?).

So I will revert to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48530/9490) by Simon Woods and pointed out by J.M.  See below for the fast implementation that lacks CSG implementation.

First, there is a shortened version of the OP's function `cuboidQ2`, followed by Simon's `contourRegionPlot3D` function, and finally I define two arbitrary rotated cuboids.

```
cuboidQ2[{x_, y_, z_}, {dim1_, dim2_, dim3_}, center_: {0, 0, 0}, 
   ang_: 0, axis_: {0, 0, 1}, p_: {0, 0, 0}] :=

  Module[{r, x1, y1, z1},
   r = TranslationTransform[-center]@*
     RotationTransform[ang, axis, p];
   {x1, y1, z1} = r[{x, y, z}];
   And @@ Thread[Abs[{x1, y1, z1}] <= {dim1, dim2, dim3}]
   ];
contourRegionPlot3D[
   region_, {x_, x0_, x1_}, {y_, y0_, y1_}, {z_, z0_, z1_}, 
     opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{reg, preds},
     reg = 
    LogicalExpand[
     region && x0 <= x <= x1 && y0 <= y <= y1 && z0 <= z <= z1];
     preds = 
    Union@Cases[
      reg, _Greater | _GreaterEqual | _Less | _LessEqual, -1];
     Show @ Table[ContourPlot3D[

      Evaluate[Equal @@ p], {x, x0, x1}, {y, y0, y1}, {z, z0, z1}, 

      RegionFunction -> 
       Function @@ {{x, y, z}, Refine[reg, p] && Refine[! reg, ! p]},
           opts], {p, preds}]];
{r1, r2} = {cuboidQ2b[{x, y, z}, {25, 35, 17}, {15, 5, -5}, \[Pi]/
     7, {1, 1, 1}],
   cuboidQ2b[{x, y, z}, {25, 35, 17}, {15, 5, -5}, \[Pi]/2, {1, 1, 
     1}]};
```

Here is a plot of the intersection, union, and difference regions:

```
contourRegionPlot3D[#, {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}, {z, -50, 50}, 
   Mesh -> None] & /@ {And[r1, r2], Or[r1, r2], And[r1, Not[r2]]}
```

[image]

I didn't show the hollow region that you get by `Xor[r1,r2]` as it is visibly identical to the intersection region.  The function is slow, but as far as quality goes, it is much much better than anything that can be achieved by `RegionPlot3D`.

### Original answer

I think there is a better way to make a rotated cube using `RegionPlot3D`.  Take OP's function `cuboidQ`,

```
RegionPlot3D[
 cuboidQ[{x , y, z}, 25, 25, 25], {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}, {z, -50,
   50}, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

And just look at those blurry edges.  When using these results for a 3D printing application, the OP had to set the `PlotPoints` all the way to 250 to get a decent edge,

[image]

The above plot, with the 250 setting, took a good deal of time to make and it is not perfect.  That isn't right, this is the simplest geometric 3D region, it shouldn't take any processing power.

Compare the above to this, which plots perfect edges instantaneously,

```
RegionPlot3D[
 DiscretizeGraphics@Cuboid[{25, 25, 25}, {-25, -25, -25}],
 Axes -> True,
 PlotRange -> {{-50, 50}, {-50, 50}, {-50, 50}}]
```

[image]

Likewise, compare the quality and execution time for the rotated version,

```
RegionPlot3D[
  cuboidQ[{x Cos[π/8] - y Sin[π/8], 
    y Cos[π/8] + x Sin[π/8], z}, 25, 25, 25], {x, -50, 
   50}, {y, -50, 50}, {z, -50, 50}, MaxRecursion -> 10, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

versus

```
RegionPlot3D[
  TransformedRegion[
   DiscretizeGraphics@Cuboid[{25, 25, 25}, {-25, -25, -25}],
   RotationTransform[π/8, {0, 0, 1}]],
  Axes -> True,
  PlotRange -> {{-50, 50}, {-50, 50}, {-50, 50}}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

If the goal of the functions is to make a cuboid that can be fed to `RegionPlot3D`, then I would suggest the following

```
cuboidQ3[ dim1_, dim2_, dim3_, center_: {0, 0, 0}, ang_: 0, 
    axis_: {0, 0, 1}, p_: {0, 0, 0}] :=
 Fold[
  TransformedRegion,
  DiscretizeGraphics@Cuboid[{-dim1, -dim2, -dim3}, {dim1, dim2, dim3}],
  {RotationTransform[ang, axis, p], TranslationTransform[center]}
  ]
```

Then you can easily plot a rotated and translated cuboid,

```
RegionPlot3D[cuboidQ3[25, 35, 17, {15, 5, -5}, π/7, {1, 1, 1}],
 Axes -> True,
 PlotRange -> {{-50, 50}, {-50, 50}, {-50, 50}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice and quick. The only drawback is that with this approach is not possible to use CSG operations (union, difference, intersection between objects). For example, this union operation fails: `RegionPlot3D[
 cuboidQ3[25, 35, 17, {15, 5, -5}, \[Pi]/7, {1, 1, 1}] || 
  cuboidQ3[25, 35, 17, {15, 5, -5}, \[Pi]/2, {1, 1, 1}], Axes -> True,
  PlotRange -> {{-50, 50}, {-50, 50}, {-50, 50}}]`

Comment: I feel like you should be able to use `RegionUnion` but it's failing.  Graphically, how would what you are trying to do there be different than `Show[RegionPlot3D[#, Axes -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {{-50, 50}, {-50, 50}, {-50, 50}}] & /@ {cuboidQ3[25,
     35, 17, {15, 5, -5}, π/7, {1, 1, 1}], 
   cuboidQ3[25, 35, 17, {15, 5, -5},π/2, {1, 1, 1}]}]`?

Comment: Graphically looks ok, but I don't think it solves my problem. How would you obtain the difference between objects? I'm usually using the difference between two objects to obtain a hollow object that can be then 3D printed.

Comment: @VLC - well then you may have to build an `ImplicitRegion` until they can make `RegionDifference`, `RegionUnion`, `RegionIntersection`, etc work on 3D regions.  This works, `RegionPlot3D[
 ImplicitRegion[
  Or[{x, y, z} ∈ 
    cuboidQ3[25, 35, 17, {15, 5, -5}, π/7, {1, 1, 1}], {x, y, 
     z} ∈ 
    cuboidQ3[25, 35, 17, {15, 5, -5}, π/2, {1, 1, 1}]], {x, y, 
   z}], Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-50, 50}, {-50, 50}, {-50, 50}}]` but you then have to increase the `PlotPoints` to get a decent plot.

Comment: Ok. But now we are actually back to the original issue, where we had to turn `PlotPoints` up to get a decent plot.

Comment: @VLC - I see that.  Until they make the region operations work on 3D mesh regions, you are left with the limitations inherent in `RegionPlot3D`.

Comment: @VLC, have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48486)?

Comment: @VLC - given that post, it would seem that even if this post were reopened it should be closed as a duplicate.  See the update above, I think it solves your problem completely.

Comment: @J.M. Not until now. Thanks.

Comment: @JasonB You are right. We can close it.