# Disobedient RegionPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions

I faced a strange behavior of a `RegionPlot3D`. I am drawing a piece of a plane bounded by a parabola. This works:

```
    RegionPlot3D[
 z < 1 - V^2 && (-0.001 < x < 0.001), {x, -0.9, 0.9}, {V, 0, 1.2}, {z,
   0, 1}]
```

[image]

Now I would like to shift it over -0.1 along x:

```
 RegionPlot3D[
 z < 1 - V^2 && ((-0.001 - 0.1) < x < (0.001 - 0.1)), {x, -0.9, 
  0.9}, {V, 0, 1.2}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

with the following result:

[image]

Do I miss something? If not, do you see a workaround?

Comment: `{x, -1, 0.8}` Works, looks like a rendering bug though

Comment: @Feyre Yes, but `-1 < x < -0.99` does not work

Comment: I think with the thinness of the slice, you just have to find a sweet spot where it will render.

Comment: add this: `PlotPoints -> {100, Automatic, Automatic}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot3D.html) for `RegionPlot3D` states

> You should realize that since it uses only a finite number of sample points, it is possible for `RegionPlot3D` to miss regions in which *pred* is `True`. To check your results, you should try increasing the settings for `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`.

This is what happened in your second example, a result of the region being so thin.

As commented by george2079, you can increase the sampling in the x direction only with the option `PlotPoints -> {100, Automatic, Automatic}`:

```
RegionPlot3D[z < 1 - V^2 && ((-0.001 - 0.1) < x < (0.001 - 0.1)), 
  {x, -0.9, 0.9}, {V, 0, 1.2}, {z, 0, 1},
  PlotPoints -> {100, Automatic, Automatic}]
```

[image]

You might also be interested in the `contourRegionPlot3D` function [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48530/862):

```
contourRegionPlot3D[z < 1 - V^2 && ((-0.001 - 0.1) < x < (0.001 - 0.1)), 
  {x, -0.9, 0.9}, {V, 0, 1.2}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the contourRegionPlot3D is certainly a good idea.