# Extruding 2D plots, subtracting extruded geometry from a 3D primitive while maintaining Graphics3D usage

Tags: graphics3d

I do have a somewhat complex question (that might be easy to solve, please bear with me I picked up Mathematica in the last two hours). I want to draw 3D shapes using Mathematica. Specifically I want to draw a rectangle, a cylinder and remove a complex shaped that can be drawn by using `Plot` or `PolarPlot` in 2D.

A good starting point would be simply removing another cylinder from my bigger cylinder. A good example on how I could draw all the shapes is shown below.

```
r = 1.2;
rPerf = 0.5;
b = 2.4;
w = 5;
l = w;
oringP = {-l/2, -l/2, 0};

cube1 = Cuboid[oringP, {w/2, l/2, 1}];
cyl1 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, b + 1}}, r];
cyl2 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 1.5}, {0, 0, b + 1}}, rPerf];

myExampleDrawing = 
 Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], cube1, cyl1, cyl2,
                AspectRatio -> Automatic,
                ImageSize -> 200}, Boxed -> False]
```

I found out I can [use RegionDifference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120597/how-to-plot-the-difference-between-two-regions) but that doesn't allow me to keep using `Graphics3D` which seems much more computational friendly and keeps smooth lines. I can generate something closer to the previous one, with the subtraction, by using the following line

```
RegionPlot3D[RegionUnion[RegionDifference[cyl1, cyl2], cube1], PlotPoints -> 70]
```

However, it has some artefacts on the union between the cuboid and the cylinder. Finally, I would like to have a complex shape instead of `cyl2`, extrude it much like in this [thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80512/extruding-a-weird-2d-shape-to-make-a-prismatic-3d-shape/80532) where a function to extrude the points is used. Then finally I'd like to subtract this extruded complex shape from the cylinder. However, I don't seem to be able to reproduce the example code (extracted from the linked answer). The code is the following:

```
R[\[Theta]_] := (1 + 0.5 Sin[2 \[Theta]]);
shape1 = PolarPlot[R[\[Theta]], {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Axes -> False,
    PlotStyle -> {Orange, Thickness[0.02]}];
points = (Flatten@shape1[[1]])[[2, 1]];
Options[Extrude] = 
  Join[Options[Graphics3D], {Closed -> True, Capped -> True}];

Extrude[curve_, {zmin_, zmax_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{info, points, color, tube, caps}, 
   info = Flatten@{curve[[1]]};
   points = Select[info, Head[#] === Line &][[1, 1]];
   If[OptionValue[Closed], points = points~Join~{points[[1]]}];
   color = Select[info, Head[#] === Directive &];
   If[Length[color] == 0, color = Orange, 
    color = First@Select[color[[1]], ColorQ]];
   tube = 
    Polygon[Partition[
      Flatten[Transpose[
        points /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y, #} & /@ {zmin, zmax}], 1], 3, 1]];
   If[OptionValue[Closed] && OptionValue[Capped], 
    caps = Polygon[points /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y, #}] & /@ {zmin, zmax};
    tube = Flatten@{tube, caps}, tube = {tube}];
   Graphics3D[Flatten@{EdgeForm[None], color, #} & /@ tube, 
    FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graphics3D]]]];
Extrude[shape1, {-2, 5}, Boxed -> False]
```

It returns several errors.

So basically I want to understand if it is possible to:

1. Create 3D geometries using subtraction of primitives and plot it using `Graphics3D`
2. Extrude 2D geometries easily
3. Create 3D geometries using subs traction of primitives and the extruded geometry while still plotting it with `Graphics3D`