# Inflate and unite a list of 0D to 2D regions

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry

I've got a List of `BoundaryMeshRegion`s, created via `ConvexHullMesh`:

```
hulls0 = ConvexHullMesh /@ RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {3, 1, 2}];
hulls1 = ConvexHullMesh /@ RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {3, 2, 2}];
hulls2 = ConvexHullMesh /@ RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {3, 3, 2}];

hulls = Flatten[List[hulls0, hulls1, hulls2]];
Show[hulls]
```

[image: regions example]

### Question

I now want to extend every region, to include also all points within a given distance `d`. Afterwards I want to obtain the union of all extended regions.

A 0D region (point) will therefore become a circle, a 1D region (line) will become two half circles with a rectangle in between, and so on.

My simple approach using

```
infReg[d_,regs_] := ImplicitRegion[RegionDistance[#, {x, y}] < d, {x, y}] & /@ regs
RegionUnion[infReg[2,hulls]]
```

doesn't work...

---

### Real test case

You can take these `hulls` to test a solution with one of my real cases: [PasteBin - Testcase](http://pastebin.com/raw/gCsyJh1x)

### Minimal test case (take `d=1`)

```
poly1 = ConvexHullMesh[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {1, -1}}];
poly2 = ConvexHullMesh[{{0, 0}, {2, 2}, {2, 0}, {0, -2}}];
hulls = {poly1, poly2}
```

Comment: `a 1D region (line) will become two half circles with a rectangle in between` - that is a stadium, in Mma since v10.2 it's called `StadiumShape`.

Comment: @kirma, interesting, I've tended to use the term "capsule" myself...

Comment: @J.M. Apparently there's `StadiumShape` for 2D and `CapsuleShape` for 3D...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here we run up against the slowness of `ImplicitRegion` and `RegionPlot` when compared to `ContourPlot`.  It's the same thing that led to [this fantastic post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48486/9490).

Here is the first instinct,

```
SeedRandom[42];
hulls0 = ConvexHullMesh /@ RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {3, 1, 2}];
hulls1 = ConvexHullMesh /@ RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {3, 2, 2}];
hulls2 = ConvexHullMesh /@ RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {3, 3, 2}];
hulls = Flatten[List[hulls0, hulls1, hulls2]];

ImplicitRegion[
  RegionDistance[hulls1[[1]], {x, y}] <= 2, {x, y}] // RegionPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

That was really slow and not accurate!  Basically, the framework underlying `ImplicitRegion` are not optimized for what we want to do. But we can take advantage of another function, which is optimized for this task.  What we want is the boundary to the region, where the `RegionDistance` is equal to some number `d`, and finding this line boundary line can be done easily and quickly by `ContourPlot`, and the result can be fed directly to `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` to create the `MeshRegion`

```
{#, BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@#} &@
 ContourPlot[
  RegionDistance[hulls1[[1]], {x, y}] == 2, {x, -7, -1}, {y, -8, 12}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now all that's left is to wrap this up in a function, taking care to figure out the bounds for the `ContourPlot` first.

Now consider

```
ClearAll[expandedMeshRegion];
expandedMeshRegion[x_MeshRegion | x_BoundaryMeshRegion, d_] := 
 Module[{xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax},
  {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = 
   Plus[#, {-1.1 d, 1.1 d}] & /@ 
    MinMax /@ Transpose[MeshCoordinates[x]];
  ContourPlot[RegionDistance[x, {xx, yy}] == d,
    {xx, xmin, xmax}, {yy, ymin, ymax}] // BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics]
```

It works super fast and seems to work with any `RegionDimension` less than 3.  It works on the whole list quickly as well

```
expandedMeshRegion[#, 2] & /@ hulls
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can combine or show the regions however you like

```
RegionUnion[expandedMeshRegion[#, 2] & /@ hulls]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is a great solution! Would you mind explaining your thoughts to some extent, so that I have a chance to understand the successive steps?

Comment: To minimize confusion, consider adding `AspectRatio -> Automatic` in your `ContourPlot[]`.

Comment: @DPF Thanks, I tried to expand the explanation a bit.  Also check out the linked post from the first sentence - it applies to 3D, but it's a great read.

Comment: exellent solution

Comment: I found a case, where this method fails. Just copy and paste this `hulls` definition: [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/raw/Yx4Jbj7F)

Comment: Do you think, it is possible to make the union already inside the ContourPlot? This might speed up the whole thing a little, when you've got many regions...

Comment: I added the test case to my question

Comment: @DPF - your pastebin doesn't work:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/p4xwW.png

Comment: @JasonB strange. Here (Mma 10.4) it works. How can I provide you the testcase?

Comment: @JasonB you can try that: [link](http://pastebin.com/raw/gCsyJh1x)  (I removed all occurences of the TJunction option)

Comment: @JasonB I added a minimal failing example above. It fails for `RegionUnion[expandedMeshRegion[#, 1] & /@ hulls]` - when `d=1`, but not for `d=2`...

Comment: @DPF - I think you are [moving the goalposts](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1808/9490) a bit.  The code here, and those below, answer the question you posted.  Further, the code in my post will work on the pastebin you edited in quite easily and quickly:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/xgtEe.png .  What you are asking now is a new question:  "Why won't `RegionUnion` work on these two simple BoundaryMeshRegions?"  The code for this question would be very succinct:  `<< "http://pastebin.com/raw/BYvkdnst";
{RegionPlot[expandedHulls], RegionUnion[expandedHulls]}`

Comment: @DPF - my point above is that the methods here work to inflate even your failing example, but it uncovers a flaw in `RegionUnion` for some reason, and that would seem to be a separate issue

Comment: @JasonB I guess, you're right. You have answered the question. I'll decide soon whether or not to open a new question.

Comment: @DPF - it's interesting, it seems to work for `RegionUnion[expandedMeshRegion[#, 1.00000001] & /@ hulls]`, but not when you add one more zero.  Definitely a bug of some kind in `RegionUnion` having to do with the fact that the two regions share a border.  To answer your question above, you can **in this case** do the `RegionUnion` before expanding the hulls and it works `expandedMeshRegion[#, 1] & /@ hulls`, but it *won't* work when the hulls contain lines and points as well.

Comment: @JasonB Interestingly, here it does not work with my edited pastebin: http://i.stack.imgur.com/w4qrL.png

Comment: @DPF - not sure about why, [works for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q59B.png) - but I have a lot of RAM. Try quitting the kernel.  Or try doing the region union one at a time with `list = expandedMeshRegion[#, 1] & /@ hulls;
Fold[RegionUnion, list]`

Comment: @JasonB which version are you using? The failure must have sth. to do with die polygons themselves. other cases with much more polygons work.

Comment: I'm on Version 10.3.1

Comment: Version 10.4.0.0 here

Comment: JasonB and @DPF I just got an automatically generated moderator flag notifying me of an excessive number of comments.  I would like to remind you that [Chat] is available for extended discussions and is really a more appropriate place for this.

Answer (score 5):

Somewhat dumb method (for instance, every line has both two `Disk`s and a `StadiumShape` overlapping), but it's not at least very complicated:

```
hulls0 = ConvexHullMesh /@ RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {3, 1, 2}];
hulls1 = ConvexHullMesh /@ RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {3, 2, 2}];
hulls2 = ConvexHullMesh /@ RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {3, 3, 2}];

hulls = Flatten@{hulls0, hulls1, hulls2};

With[
 {r = 1},
 BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion@@
  (RegionUnion@@
    (MeshPrimitives[#, 0 | 1 | 2] /.
     {Point[pt_] :> Disk[pt, r],
      Line[line_] :> StadiumShape[line, r]}) & /@ hulls)]]
```

[image]

Comment: Uncomplicated is good sometimes. +1

Comment: A side note: this method is not applicable to input boundary mesh regions with holes inside them. Of course, that shouldn't be an issue with convex hulls...

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly more compact than Jason's proposal, except that it throws a bunch of `Compile::cpw` errors that seem to not affect the final result (and thus, you can use `Quiet[]` if they bother you):

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42];
            hulls0 = ConvexHullMesh /@ RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {3, 1, 2}];
            hulls1 = ConvexHullMesh /@ RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {3, 2, 2}];
            hulls2 = ConvexHullMesh /@ RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {3, 3, 2}];]
hulls = Flatten[{hulls0, hulls1, hulls2}];

inflateAndJoinRegions[hulls_List, d_?NumericQ, opts___] := 
       RegionUnion[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
                   ImplicitRegion[RegionDistance[
                                  With[{k = RegionDimension[#]}, 
                                       If[k < 2, First[MeshPrimitives[#, k]], #]],
                                  {\[FormalX], \[FormalY]}]^2 <= d^2,
                                  {\[FormalX], \[FormalY]}], opts, 
                   Method -> "RegionPlot"] & /@ hulls]

Table[inflateAndJoinRegions[hulls, d, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.2}] // Quiet,
      {d, {1/2, 1, 2}}] // GraphicsRow
```

[image: inflated regions]