# Why does RegionUnion fail for these Regions?

Tags: bugs, computational-geometry, regions

**Bug introduced in v10.0, resolved in v11.0.**

---

### Introduction

Lately, I asked for a solution to inflate and unite a List of `BoundaryMeshRegions`: [Inflate and unite a list of 0D to 2D regions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121016/inflate-and-unite-a-list-of-0d-to-2d-regions)

[JasonB](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9490/jasonb) came up with a very good approach, using `ContourPlot` to do the hard work, instead of `ImplicitRegion`.

### Problem

Now it happens, that the solution seems to fail for some cases of my application (I use PasteBin to save my List of regions for convenience reasons):

```
Quit;
ClearAll[expandedMeshRegion];
expandedMeshRegion[x_MeshRegion | x_BoundaryMeshRegion, d_: 2] := 
 Module[{xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax}, {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = 
   Plus[#, {-1.1 d, 1.1 d}] & /@ 
    MinMax /@ Transpose[MeshCoordinates[x]];
  ContourPlot[
    RegionDistance[x, {xx, yy}] == d, {xx, xmin, xmax}, {yy, ymin, 
     ymax}] // BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics]

<< http://pastebin.com/raw/Yx4Jbj7F;

expandedMeshRegion[#, 10] & /@ hulls // RegionUnion
```

Interestingly, it works for the polygons in [this case](http://pastebin.com/raw/fMBvnc6G) `<< http://pastebin.com/raw/fMBvnc6G;` with double as many regions.

**Side Info**

- Mathematica 10.4.0.0

Comment: TechSupport has kindly filed an incident report to the developers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simplified minimal example from `{hulls[[6]], hulls[[12]]}` (similarly failes if you replace `BoundaryMeshRegion` with `MeshRegion`):

```
SeedRandom@1;
b1 = BoundaryMeshRegion[
    {{142., -82.}, {187., -56.}, {142., -133.8}, {187., -108.}},
    {Line[{{3, 4}, {4, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 3}}]},
    Properties -> {}, Method -> {}];
b2 = BoundaryMeshRegion[
    {{187., -56.}, {231., -82.2}, {97.7, -108.}, {142., -133.}},
    {Line[{{3, 4}, {4, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 3}}]},
    Properties -> {}, Method -> {}];
RegionUnion[b1, b2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

These two are not joined. The alarming thing is, that if you evaluate it a couple more times, **the order with which the unevaluated `RegionUnion` returns is not the same, regardless of `SeedRandom`**. I would consider it a bug, and a twofold at that: internal numerical imprecisions (?) inhibit joining and the internal method of `RegionUnion` is immune to `SeedRandom`.

`RegionBounds` indicates that the bounds are almost identical along the *y* dimension.

```
RegionBounds /@ test
```

> ```
> {{{142.375, 187.061}, {-133.8, -56.4}}, {{97.6877, 231.748}, {-133.8, -56.4}}}
> ```

### Workaround 1: Coordinate offset

A possible workaround is to slightly offset all or one appropriate coordinate and transform the region a bit. Note, that the visible lip is due to me rounding the original `hulls` coordinates but is not the effect of the slight coordinate shift.

```
b2 = BoundaryMeshRegion[
    {{187., -56.}, {231., -82.2}, {97.7, -108.}, {142., -133.}} + 
     10^-6,
    {Line[{{3, 4}, {4, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 3}}]},
    Properties -> {}, Method -> {}];
 RegionUnion[b1, b2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Workaround 2: Convert to `Polygon`s

TechSupport kindly suggested the following workaround:

```
b1 = Polygon[{{142., -82.}, {187., -56.}, {187., -108.}, {142., -133.8}}]
b2 = Polygon[{{187., -56.}, {231., -82.2}, {142., -133.}, {97.7, -108.}}]
b = RegionUnion[b1, b2] (* Note, that this does not really join the polygons *)
RegionPlot[b, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can easily extract the `Polygon` represenations by using `MeshPrimitives`. Then you can then simply plot the result as a list of graphics primitives:

```
exp  = expandedMeshRegion[#, 10] &/@ hulls;
poly = Chop@Flatten[MeshPrimitives[#, 2] &/@ exp];
Graphics[{{RandomColor[], #} &/@ poly}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or ypu can join individual primitives into one big `Polygon` - this of course only works so simply if the individual polygons are all convex.

```
comb = Polygon @ (Join @@ List @@@ poly);  (* would have been nice without the parenthesis *)
Graphics@{Blue, comb}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Don't try to discretize the resulting combined `Polygon`:

```
BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@comb
```

> ```
>  BoundaryMeshRegion::bcinsect: -- Message text not found -- ...
> ```

Joining the polygons as regions and plotting the result with `RegionPlot` also fails and on my machine it **crashes the kernel**.

```
(* Be advased, this might crash your kernel *)
RegionPlot @ (RegionUnion @@ poly)
```

Comment: A good view on that issue :). Thanks for submitting it to the TechSupport. Do you have any Idea, how I could handle this issue with lists of regions, like I have in the PasteBin? Shifting polygons is kind of acceptable, if the shift is $10^{-9}$ smaller than the coordinates, but the function must not fail...

Comment: I guess, the main problem would be, to identify the pairs of regions, that fail together.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation!

Comment: The `RegionUnion` of `BoundaryMeshRegion` in your first example now works in 11.0.

Comment: Thanks @Xavier, changed the boilerplate in the question accordingly.