# Region rotated about the line y=2

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

Could a few people share the best way to display the image created by rotating the region bounded by $y=x^4$ and $y=1$ about the line $y=2$?

Thanks.

**Update:** I took JasonB's hint and tried this:

```
Show[
 RevolutionPlot3D[x^4 - 2, {x, -1, 1}, RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0},
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "z", "y"}],
 RevolutionPlot3D[-1, {x, -1, 1}, RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}]
 ]
```

Which gave this image:

[image]

How can I change the ticks on the y-axis to run from 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4?

Thanks.

**Second Update:**

Looks like I found an answer to my tick question.

```
Manipulate[
 RevolutionPlot3D[{{x^4 - 2}, {1 - 2}}, {x, -1, 1}, {\[Theta], 0, 
   tau}, RevolutionAxis -> "X",
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}},
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "z", "y"},
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
  Ticks -> {Automatic, 
    Automatic, {{-2, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}}}],
 {{tau, 0.1}, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

Comment: Have you looked into [`RevolutionPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RevolutionPlot3D.html)?

Comment: @ChipHurst I would like to see an answer that uses RevolutionPlot3D.

Comment: Ok, I added an answer.

Answer (score 6):

One option is to define the 3D region you want to plot in terms of a set of boolean predicates and feed them to Simon Woods's [`contourRegionPlot3D`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48530/9490) (follow link for the code).

Here's the region you want to rotate

```
Plot[{x^4, 1}, {x, -1, 1}, PlotRangePadding -> 0.1, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And here's the region plot

```
contourRegionPlot3D[
 1 <= z^2 + (y - 2)^2 <= (2 - x^4)^2 && -1 <= x <= 1,
 {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1, 5}, {z, -3, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can dress up the style as you see fit,

```
contourRegionPlot3D[
 1 <= z^2 + (y - 2)^2 <= (2 - x^4)^2 && -1 <= x <= 1,
 {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1, 5}, {z, -3, 3},
 Mesh -> None,
 Boxed -> False,
 Axes -> False,
 ContourStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.6]],
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you shift to rotate about $y = 0$, you can use `RevolutionPlot3D`.

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{{x^4 - 2}, {1 - 2}}, {x, -1, 1}, RevolutionAxis -> "X"]
```

[image]

---

## Edit

The only I can think to correct the ticks (when using `RevolutionPlot3D`) is somewhat clunky...

```
a = 2;
plot = RevolutionPlot3D[{{x^4 - a}, {1 - a}}, {x, -1, 1}, RevolutionAxis -> "X"];

Show[
  plot /. g_GraphicsComplex :> Translate[g, {0, 0, a}],
  PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This adds some more understanding for me. Can you check out the question in my update? How can I change the labels on the vertical axis to 0,1,2,3, and 4?

Comment: @David I updated my answer. I couldn't find a clean way to do it however.

Comment: Wow! Nice answer.

Comment: Looks like I've found an answer. See the second update to my original post. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:

```
pp = ParametricPlot3D[
   RotationMatrix[v, {1, 0, 0}].{u, 0, (u^4 - 2)} + {0, 0, 2}, {u, -1,
     1}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{LightBlue, Opacity[0.5]}, Directive[Red, Thick]}, 
   Mesh -> None];
plane = Plot3D[1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Mesh -> False, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3]];
curves[angle_] := 
  ParametricPlot3D[{RotationMatrix[angle, {1, 0, 0}].{u , 0, 
       u^4 - 2} + {0, 0, 2}, {u, 0, 2}}, {u, -1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thickness[0.02]}}];
Manipulate[Show[pp, plane, curves[a]], {a, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]