# Rotate an area between curves around the y axis

Tags: plotting

[image]I'm struggling to figure out how to do this in Mathematica and really need some help. I'm pretty new to mathematica... 
I need  to plot the solid of revolution obtained by rotating the region enclosed by the graphs of

`x^2=y-2  ,2y-x-2=0  , x=0 , x=1`

around y=3....
So far, I tried this :

```
 Show[RevolutionPlot3D[(x + 2)/2 - (x^2 + 2), {x, 0, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Classic", RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}]
```

But I'm not having what I need, it's not "filled"...
The volume resulting of the revolution should be 51pi/20 (if it's useful) ...
Thank you in advance

Comment: closely related: [**41985**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41985/5478), [**126862**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/126862/5478), [**136610**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136610/5478)

Comment: 51pi/20 is the result of the volume obtained by the revolution of the surface around the  axis

Comment: another closely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27645/5478

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

On the basis of discussion in comments:

```
Integrate[r, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {z, 0, 1}, {r, z^2 - 1, (z + 2)/2 - 3}]
RegionPlot3D[(x^2 - 1)^2 < y^2 + z^2 < ((x + 2)/2 - 3)^2, {x, 0, 
  1}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5],
  BoxRatios -> Automatic, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 Background -> Black]
```

[image]

**Original Answer**

I am not sure I have correctly interpreted the aim and I am unsure what the "answer" is (volume,surface area etc). However, I post this in caseitmay motivate the desired answer:

The solid of revolution can be plotted (with less than ideal cosmetic result) using[`RegionPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot3D.html):

```
RegionPlot3D[
 0 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && 
  1/2 (2 + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]) <= z <= 2 + x^2 + y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1,
   1}, {z, 1, 4}, PlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> None, Background -> Black,
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.6], 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

[image]

A more pleasing cosmetic result can be done by just plotting bounding  surfaces:

```
p = {u Cos[v], u Sin[v], u^2 + 2};
c = { Cos[v], Sin[v], u};
l = {u Cos[v], u Sin[v], (u + 2)/2};
Show[ParametricPlot3D[l, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None], 
 ParametricPlot3D[p, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None], 
 ParametricPlot3D[c, {u, 3/2, 3}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7]], PlotRange -> {0, 3}, 
 Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Calculating the volume using[`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html):

```
vol = Volume[
  ImplicitRegion[
   0 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && 
    1/2 (2 + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]) <= z <= 2 + x^2 + y^2, {{x, -1, 
     1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 1, 3}}]]
```

Calculating the volume using integration of cylindrical coordinates:

```
int = Integrate[
  Det[D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], z}, {{r, t, z}}]], {r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 
   2 Pi}, {z, (r + 2)/2, r^2 + 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, the result obtained by plotting bounding surfaces seems to be what I need but isn't the surface revolving around the y axis... Thank you so much anyway, I will try to make il revolve around the x axis

Comment: @SebastienMartinez  that should just be a matter of permitting the parametric definition to desired aim. Good luck. Sorry for misreading axis:)

Comment: Yep, no problem ;) So I guess that I have to change"p", "c" and "l" ?

Comment: @SebastienMartinez yes. You know what you are after. Adjust, test, readjust till write and along the way you get insight into Mathematica. It is midnight in my TZ so I am off to sleep:)

Comment: NIce ! Thanks a lot, good night :)

Comment: Hey,sorry to come back again but I tried at lost of things and I managed to have something a bit closer of what I need but It still misses some parts and does'nt really seem's to be precisely the form that shoulb be generated by the rotation...Could you give me a clue of what I should do ?

Comment: @SebastienMartinez the permuting just allows to see the same surface  with different orientation. Rotation about another axis? Is this what you want?: `RegionPlot3D[(x + 2)^2/4 < y^2 + z^2 < (x^2 + 2)^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -3,
   3}, {z, -3, 3}, Mesh -> None, Background -> Black, Axes -> False, 
 Boxed -> False]`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response... I do want to make it rotate about the x axis but it doesn't really seems to be what you showed me.... I just edited my post with an image of the integral that I need to rotate... I did a translation of -3 so the y=3 (wich I need to rotate around) becomes the x axis... so I applied this translation to the functions that become : y=x^2-1 and (x-4)/2... I tried again a few things but can't obtain what I need.... Ps : I may be using the word "translation" wrong, can't find how to say it in english, I just want to mean that I move it down –

Comment: @SebastienMartinez see my update

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help !! It's perfect, really appreciate it !