# Polytopes package for represents the intersection of elements

Tags: regions, geometry

How do I use the [`Hexagon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hexagon.html) function of the `Polytopes package`?

I am not understanding what is shown in the documentation. I do not see any parameters.

Different from [`Circle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Circle.html) function where I enter the center value, radius value, ...

[image]

**EDIT**

Actually, my goal is to apply a Boolean operation so that I get this geometry.

[image]

The procedure I have in mind is to create a 3D hexagon and a sphere with a certain thickness. With this I could apply some command that get a geometry that represents the intersection of these elements.

In the image the ball is cut in half for just visualization. In fact the sphere is whole to make the intersection.

My attempts:

```
ℛ = 
  RegionDifference[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 10], Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 9]];
DiscretizeRegion[ℛ]
```

[image]

I have identified the points for my Hexagon

```
transform = CoordinateTransformData["Polar" -> "Cartesian", "Mapping"];
{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6} = 
 transform[{2 Sqrt[3], # Degree}] & /@ Most[Subdivide[360, 6] + 30] //
   N

Graphics[{Black, Line[{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p1}], Dashed, Red, 
  Circle[{0, 0}, 3]}]
```

[image]

Here I tried to define all the vertices:

```
p0h = {{3., 1.7320508075688772, 0}, {0., 3.4641016151377544, 
    0}, {-3., 1.7320508075688772, 0}, {-3., -1.7320508075688772, 
    0}, {0., -3.4641016151377544, 0}, 
      {3., -1.7320508075688772, 0}};
p15h = {{3., 1.7320508075688772, 15}, {0., 3.4641016151377544, 
    15}, {-3., 1.7320508075688772, 15}, {-3., -1.7320508075688772, 
    15}, {0., -3.4641016151377544, 15}, 
      {3., -1.7320508075688772, 15}};
```

But it does not work:

```
hex = Hexahedron[Join[p0h, p15h]];
Graphics3D[{Pink, hex}]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is a nice picture, you can use `contourRegionPlot3D[]` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48530):

```
(* by Simon Woods *)
contourRegionPlot3D[region_, {x_, x0_, x1_}, {y_, y0_, y1_}, {z_, z0_, z1_}, 
                    opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
       Module[{reg, preds}, 
              reg = LogicalExpand[region &&
                                  x0 <= x <= x1 && y0 <= y <= y1 && z0 <= z <= z1];
              preds = Union @ Cases[reg, _Greater | _GreaterEqual |
                                         _Less | _LessEqual, -1];
              Show @ Table[ContourPlot3D[Evaluate[Equal @@ p],
                                         {x, x0, x1}, {y, y0, y1}, {z, z0, z1}, 
                                         RegionFunction -> Function @@ {{x, y, z},
                                         Refine[reg, p] && Refine[! reg, ! p]}, 
                                         opts], {p, preds}]]

With[{r1 = 9/10, r2 = 1, r = 3/4}, 
     contourRegionPlot3D[RegionMember[SphericalShell[{0, 0, 0}, {r1, r2}], {x, y, z}] && 
                         RegionMember[RegularPolygon[r, 6], {x, y}] && z > 0,
                         {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
                         BoxRatios -> Automatic, Mesh -> False]]
```

[image: hexagonal spherical slab]

Comment: With your license, I could edit your answer to append the code you just referenced. I think it's important to show this `contourRegionPlot3D[]` function in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

*Edit: RegularPolygon*

I think they are used as symbolic objects rather than like a function, so you could write `Vertices[Hexagon]` for example.  This does mean you can't set certain properties of the object, but that doesn't seem to be the aim of the package.  If you want to make regular shapes like that with inputs you could use:

```
Polygon[(# + {1, 1}) & /@ CirclePoints[6]]
```

Where `{1,1}` is the position of the centre of the shape and `6` is the number of vertices.

If you want a pre-built function there is `RegularPolygon` as pointed out by J.M. which seems to do pretty much exactly the same thing.

Comment: ...or use `RegularPolygon[]`.

Comment: Yeah fair enough.  I never really encountered it before so it didn't come to mind.  I'll edit it in.

Comment: @Caio, why not look through the docs for those functions? You'll see that it can take a "radius" argument corresponding to its circumradius.

Comment: @Caio, then why not edit your question to mention that requirement?