# Trying to plot a region in 3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions

I'm trying to plot the region enclosed by the curves

$$\begin{cases}y^2=x\\y^2=4-x\\z=0\\z=3\end{cases}$$

using the command `RegionPlot`  (I'm not sure if `Plot3D` or `ParametricPlot3D` are more appropriate). The desired region looks like a cylinder but with a parabolic-intersection cross section:

[image: My bad drawing]

Now I'm running the command

```
RegionPlot3D[y^2 < x && y^2 < 4 - x && z > 0 && z < 3, {x, 0, 4}, {y, -3,  3}, {z, -3, 3}]
```

But I get the following weird-looking region instead.

[image: Resulting Region]

Can anyone help me plot the desired region? and is there perhaps a better/more suitable command for such a thing?

Comment: Try `contourRegionPlot3D[]` from [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48486).

Comment: @J.M. - it sorted it! Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increasing the number of `PlotPoints` results in a more satisfactory plot.

```
RegionPlot3D[y^2 < x && y^2 < 4 - x && z > 0 && z < 3,
 {x, 0, 4},
 {y, -3, 3},
 {z, -3, 3},
 PlotPoints -> 100
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

In version 11 just simply confining argument to x,y dependence yields a satisfactory result:

```
 RegionPlot3D[y^2 < x && y^2 < 4 - x, {x, 0, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, 0, 3},
  Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 40]
```

[image]