# Unexpected DiscretizeGraphics behaviour

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions, discretization

One way to generate an annulus is by using `ChartElementData`:

```
annulusArc = ChartElementData["CylindricalSector3D"]
annulusArc[{{3 \[Pi]/64, 28 \[Pi]/64}, {1.4, 1.6}, {1.4, 1.6}}, 1] // Graphics3D
```

[image: d1]

Moreover, for my purposes (RegionIntersection) I need to obtain its region. One way of doing it is by discretizing graphics, however by doing so, it produces an unexpected result:

```
annulusArc // DiscretizeGraphics // MeshRegion // RegionPlot3D
```

[image]

What causes this "anomaly" and how can one fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the polygons in your graphics object are hitting a bug in `DiscretizeGraphics`.  A minimal example, using the definition in the OP is `{Graphics3D@#, DiscretizeGraphics@#} &@ annulusArc[[1, 1]]`

I can offer a workaround which involves constructing the region in question as a boolean region.

```
region = 1.4 < x^2 + y^2 < 1.6 && 1.4 < z < 1.6 && 
         3 π/64 < ArcTan[x, y] < 28 π/64;
```

This gives a reasonable result, but takes a very long time

```
RegionPlot3D[
  region,
  {x, 0.1, 2}, {y, 0.1, 2}, {z, 1.2, 1.8}, 
  PlotPoints -> 300] // DiscretizeGraphics
```

This is fast, and uses the `contourRegionPlot3D` function from  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48530/9490

```
contourRegionPlot3D[
 region,
 {x, 0.1, 2}, {y, 0.1, 2}, {z, 1.2, 1.8}] // DiscretizeGraphics
```

My favorite, but does not work in older versions of *Mathematica*.  Set the `MaxCellMeasure` to what you like.  This is the only method listed here that gives a region with `RegionDimension` of 3.

```
DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[region, {x,y,z}], MaxCellMeasure -> .000001]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]