# Discordance in plots

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

Let us solve the system with `Floor`s

```
sol = Reduce[{4*x1 + 7*x2 + 6*x3 == 186,Floor[(1/2)*x1] + Floor[(1/5)*x2] + 
Floor[(1/3)*x3] == 18,Floor[(1/5)*x1] + Floor[(1/2)*x2] + Floor[(1/4)*x3] == 21}, 
{x1, x2, x3}, Reals]
```

> ((155/2 < x1 < 78 && 1/7 (744 - 4 x1) < x2 < 62) || (72 <= x1 <= 73 &&
>         1/7 (714 - 4 x1) < x2 < 62) || (73 < x1 <= 147/2 && 
>        1/7 (714 - 4 x1) < x2 <= 1/7 (726 - 4 x1)) || (147/2 < x1 < 74 &&
>         60 <= x2 <= 1/7 (726 - 4 x1)) || (74 <= x1 < 75 && 
>        1/7 (726 - 4 x1) < x2 < 62) || (153/2 < x1 < 78 && 
>        1/7 (726 - 4 x1) < x2 < 60) || (x1 == 72 && 
>        58 <= x2 < 60) || (72 < x1 < 74 && 
>        58 <= x2 <= 1/7 (708 - 4 x1)) || (75 <= x1 < 76 && 
>        1/7 (714 - 4 x1) < x2 < 60) || (x1 == 74 && 
>        442/7 < x2 < 64) || (74 < x1 < 75 && 
>        1/7 (738 - 4 x1) < x2 <= 1/7 (744 - 4 x1)) || (74 <= x1 < 75 && 
>        1/7 (708 - 4 x1) < x2 <= 1/7 (714 - 4 x1)) || (151/2 < x1 < 76 &&
>         1/7 (708 - 4 x1) < x2 < 58) || (157/2 < x1 < 80 && 
>        1/7 (762 - 4 x1) < x2 < 64) || (68 <= x1 < 137/2 && 
>        56 <= x2 <= 1/7 (666 - 4 x1)) || (x1 == 137/2 && 
>        x2 == 56) || (x1 == 70 && 56 < x2 < 58) || (70 < x1 <= 71 && 
>        56 <= x2 < 58) || (71 < x1 < 72 && 
>        56 <= x2 <= 1/7 (690 - 4 x1)) || (70 <= x1 <= 281/4 && 
>        54 <= x2 < 55) || (281/4 < x1 < 72 && 
>        54 <= x2 <= 1/7 (666 - 4 x1))) && x3 == 1/6 (186 - 4 x1 - 7 x2)

and plot it

```
Region[ImplicitRegion[sol, {x1, x2, x3}]]
```

[image]

Nice. Let us verify it by

```
FindInstance[{4*x1 + 7*x2 + 6*x3 == 186, 
Floor[(1/2)*x1] + Floor[(1/5)*x2] + Floor[(1/3)*x3] == 18, 
   Floor[(1/5)*x1] + Floor[(1/2)*x2] + Floor[(1/4)*x3] == 21}, {x1, x2, x3}, Reals, 300];
a = {x1, x2, x3} /. %;
ListPlot3D[a, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

At least one of the above results is incorrect. The question arises: which result is true?

Addition. One more different result is obtained by (Many thanks from me to Mariusz Iwaniuk.)

```
S = FindInstance[{4*x1 + 7*x2 + 6*x3 == 186, 
Floor[(1/2)*x1] + Floor[(1/5)*x2] + Floor[(1/3)*x3] == 18, 
Floor[(1/5)*x1] + Floor[(1/2)*x2] + Floor[(1/4)*x3] == 21}, {x1, x2, x3}, 
Reals, 5000, RandomSeeding -> Automatic]; ListPointPlot3D[Evaluate[{x1, x2, x3} /. S], 
PlotRange -> Full, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.01]]
```

[image]

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: Sorry, I find your edit as not reasonable.

Comment: No? Well, you are free to roll it back. Notice that originally, you had `{x1, 2, x3}` instead of `{x1, x2, x3}` as second argument of `Reduce` so that running it produced the  error message `General::ivar`.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: But the whole code was seen. Using the opportunity, many thanks from me to you for your edit of my previous question.

Comment: Region gives **wrong** answer.Let's: `FindInstance[{4*x1 + 7*x2 + 6*x3 == 186, 
   Floor[(1/2)*x1] + Floor[(1/5)*x2] + Floor[(1/3)*x3] == 18, 
   Floor[(1/5)*x1] + Floor[(1/2)*x2] + Floor[(1/4)*x3] == 21}, {x1, 
   x2, x3}, Reals, 10000, RandomSeeding -> Automatic];
a = {x1, x2, x3} /. %;
ListPointPlot3D[a, PlotRange -> Full, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.01]]`

Comment: @Mariusz Iwanyuk: First, can't reproduce your code on my comp, obtaining ReplaceAll::reps: {} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. Second, your statement is ungrounded. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Ok I corrected the code :`S = FindInstance[{4*x1 + 7*x2 + 6*x3 == 186, 
   Floor[(1/2)*x1] + Floor[(1/5)*x2] + Floor[(1/3)*x3] == 18, 
   Floor[(1/5)*x1] + Floor[(1/2)*x2] + Floor[(1/4)*x3] == 21}, {x1, 
   x2, x3}, Reals, 10000, 
  RandomSeeding -> Automatic]; ListPointPlot3D[
 Evaluate[{x1, x2, x3} /. S], PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.01]]`, **:)**

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk: Thank you. I added it to my question.