# Eliminating the sawtooth edges in an image and improving the rending

Tags: plotting

```
RegionPlot3D[(x - 45/2)^2 + y^2 + z^2 >= 25/
   4 && (x - 15)^2 + y^2 + z^2 >= 25 && (x - 35/2)^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 
   225/4, {x, -5, 35}, {y, -15, 15}, {z, -15, 15}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

The image output by this code is of very poor quality. How can I improve it.

Comment: PlotPoints->250 or PlotPoints->500 but then you will perhaps reply "why does it take so long to produce textbook or art quality images and how can I make it do it instantly?"

Comment: If you use `contourRegionPlot3D[]` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48530), you'll get a better picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw extra boundary. Is slightly faster.

```
cond = (x - 45/2)^2 + y^2 + z^2 >= 25/4 && (x - 15)^2 + y^2 + z^2 >= 
       25 && (x - 35/2)^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 225/4;

cond2 = List @@ (Equal @@ # & /@ cond)

rp = RegionPlot3D[cond, {x, 10, 25}, {y, 0, 8}, {z, -8, 8}, 
        PlotPoints -> 100];

cp = ContourPlot3D[
       Evaluate[cond2], {x, 10, 25}, {y, 0, 8}, {z, -8, 8}, 
       PlotPoints -> 50];

Show[cp, rp]
```

[image]