# RegionPlot3D over non-rectangular range

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions

I want to make a `RegionPlot3D` only in the range `x + y + z < 1`.  The following works, but is slow and poor quality.

```
ρ12 = ρ23 = ρ31 = 0.4;
a12 = a23 = a31 = 2;

RegionPlot3D[{
  1/ρ12 > a12 x/y > ρ12 && x + y + z < 1,
  1/ρ23 > a23 y/z > ρ23 && x + y + z < 1,
  1/ρ31 > a31 z/x > ρ31 && x + y + z < 1
  }, {x, 10^-10, 1}, {y, 10^-10, 1}, {z, 10^-10, 1},
 PlotPoints -> 101, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Mesh -> None, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Any ideas on how to make this sharper looking (highest priority) and faster (lower priority)?  I'm not wedded to using `RegionPlot3D` if there are approaches using different functions.

Bonus question: can I make the faces towards the viewer a different style?

Comment: You could try `DiscretizeRegion` with an `ImplicitRegion` to give finer-grained control over how the regions are meshed, but this keeps crashing my 12.1 kernel

Comment: Are these the only types of regions you'll want to plot? If so, it might be worth solving for the appropriate coordinates, and building them as `Polyhedra` or directly as `MeshRegion`s.

Comment: You could also try using `Tetrahedron[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]` to represent your target region and use `RegionIntersection` with that. Or you could use `RegionBoundary` and apply your transformations to the boundary and see what pops out

Comment: Region stuff seems buggy on my copy of Mathematica, but yet _another_ idea is to use `TransformedRegion` on `Tetrahedron` and take the intersection with your boundary conditions and then invert the transformation

Comment: I just found [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48486/6358) which is showing promise...

Answer (score 1):

Putting together some hints from @b3m2a1 and @thorimur, this works great (although not quite as automated as `RegionPlot3D`):

```
simplex3 = Tetrahedron[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}];
Graphics3D[{
  {Opacity[0.5], ColorData[97, 1], 
   RegionIntersection[simplex3, 
    Prism[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, a12/ρ12, 0}, {1, a12 ρ12, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, a12/ρ12, 1}, {1, a12 ρ12, 1}}]]},
  {Opacity[0.5], ColorData[97, 2], 
   RegionIntersection[simplex3, 
    Prism[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, a23/ρ23}, {0, 1, a23 ρ23}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, a23/ρ23}, {1, 1, a23 ρ23}}]]},
  {Opacity[0.5], ColorData[97, 3], 
   RegionIntersection[simplex3, 
    Prism[{{0, 0, 0}, {a31/ρ31, 0, 1}, {a31 ρ31, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {a31/ρ31, 1, 1}, {a31 ρ31, 1, 1}}]]}
  }]
```

[image]