# Problem in highlighting regions in RegionPlot3D

Tags: plotting, regions, legending

In the following RegionPlot3D

```
  f1 = Sin[x y]; f2 = x + y; f3 = x + z;
RegionPlot3D[
 f1 < 1 && f2 < 1 && f3 < 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 35, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

I want to understand how to highlight (kind of "PlotLegend") the regions f1, f2, f3.

Comment: You might be able to adapt the solution [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48486) so that the pieces are colored the way you want them.

Comment: Since `f1<=1` always true, maybe you wan to set `f1 < 1/8` for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f1 = Sin[x y]; f2 = x + y; f3 = x + z;

data1 = Transpose[{
    (Rest@
      Subsets[
       {f1 < 1/8, f2 < 1/2, f3 < 1/2},
       3]),
    Rest@
     Subsets[
      Opacity[0.5, ColorData[97][#]] & /@
       Range[3],
      3]}];

data2 = ReplacePart[#, 1 -> And @@ #[[1]]] & /@ data1;

data = Drop[Riffle[data1, data2], {1, 5, 2}];

Partition[
  Insert[RegionPlot3D[Evaluate@#[[1]],
      {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
      PlotStyle -> #[[2]],
      PlotRange ->
       {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}},
      PlotPoints -> 50,
      MaxRecursion -> 7,
      PlotRange -> All,
      AxesLabel -> Automatic,
      PlotLabel ->
       StringForm["``", #[[1]]]] & /@
    data,
   SpanFromLeft, 4],
  2] // Grid
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but there is some problem. When I run, it shows "{Sin[x\ y]<1/8,x+y<1/2} must be a Boolean function"   (I am using version 11.3 on Windows 19). Could you write more simply what data1, data2 and data mean? And what Evaluate@#[[1]] stands for?

Comment: The error message "{Sin[x\ y]<1/8,x+y<1/2} must be a Boolean function" appears to indicate an extraneous backslash character was inserted. Did you copy and paste from above or retype the input? The `RegionPlot3D` expression is being mapped onto the list `data`. The `#` is an element of the list data. The element of the list is itself a list. `#[[1]]` is the fist part (element) of that sublist. `Evaluate@#[[1]]` is equivalent to `Evaluate[#[[1]]]` If you don't recognize an operator or function, highlight it in Mathematica and press `F1` for help.