# How to get a smooth plot of a volume with a cylindrical hole?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a "wavy" cuboid with a hole in it. The final result does not look great because of jagged edges of the cylindrical hole. Are there any ways to fix it?

I have tried to increase the PlotPoints option to 150 but it is taking nearly a minute without significant improvements.

Is there a smarter way to circumvent this problem?

My code is attached below (MMA 13.1):

```
RegionPlot3D[z > Sin[x + y^2]/10 && z < 2 + Sin[x + y^2]/10 && (x - 1)^2 + y^2 > 1,
 {x,-5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -1, 7}, PlotPoints -> 100, MeshStyle -> None]
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Also use the option `MaxRecursion`, e.g., `PlotPoints -> 120, MaxRecursion -> 5`

Comment: You may be interested in the `countourRegionPlot3D` function developed in [High-quality RegionPlot3D for logical combinations of predicates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48486/27951).

Answer (score 1):

With a restricted z range, I get the following picture:

```
RegionPlot3D[
 z > Sin[x + y^2]/10 && 
  z < 2 + Sin[x + y^2]/10 && (x - 1)^2 + y^2 > 1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 
  5}, {z, -0.5, 2.5}, PlotPoints -> 100, MeshStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe I am missing the obvious, but isn't the cylindrical hole still jagged in the picture you've attached? Also, I have other elements on my plot (that I have not included), so I would like the z plot range to be a little larger, in case that changes anything.

Comment: Simply increase PlotPoints. You may increase the z range, this does change nothing essential.

Comment: Okay, so looks like it means that increasing PlotPoints is the only way to go. (My question specifically asked for ways apart from this approach because it takes more and more time.)

Comment: It may be possible to get refinement at the cylinder intersection with BoundaryMeshRegion where you specify finely spaced vertices and edges along the intersections programmatically--or programmatically with a MeshRefinementFunction.  It would be tedious.